# Devise controllers rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controllers

I'm using Rails 3, on ruby 1.8.7. And using for auth. devise (1.1.3). But it is a quite large community site i'm building, so i have a table for profiles and a table for users. And every time a user registers it should generate a profile also, but in devise i'm not allowed the controllers, so i'm completely lost..

**Edit**

Now it says

```
undefined method `getlocal' for Tue, 28 Dec 2010 11:18:55 +0000:DateTime
```

Then when i make a file in lib called date_time.rb with this code

```
class DateTime
  def getlocal
    "it works"
  end
end
```

And require it in my Application controller it gives me this

```
fail wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

it is like it don't know anything called devise anymore, but in my routes i do have devise

```
devise_for :users
```

Comment: There is a comment referring to a 'getlocal' error on the Devise issues pages: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/issue/240#issue/240/comment/532309 Perhaps a record has been corrupted - maybe try a db:reset to clear your data?

Comment: Omg i can't believe that was all.... Thank you, thank you so much!

Comment: In all honesty - it was a guess... but thanks!

Comment: Guess or not, it worked, and now back on the first problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can subclass the Devise RegistrationsController and add your own logic in the create() method, and call the parent class methods for everything else.

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_view_path "app/views/devise"

  def create
    super
    # Generate your profile here
    # ...
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

If you want to customise the Devise views that are packaged inside the Gem then you can run the following command to generate the view files for your app:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

You will also need to tell the router to use your new controller; something like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "my_registrations" }
```

Comment: With that, could i then just super on everything and then make my own? or.

Comment: i think you should make your own things and then call super

Comment: I added the call to super in update() to remind you to call the it as appropriate. In fact you should probably call super in create() too. I'll add that to my example.

Comment: but why canøt i just say def create super #my code end and then no more?

Comment: You can, you don't need to call super() in update(). My example is perhaps not the best. Apologies :-)

Comment: So know i can again focus on my real problem, it gives me this "Template is missing

Missing template users/registrations/new with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rhtml, :haml, :rxml, :builder, :rjs], :locale=>[:da, :da], :formats=>[:html]} in view paths "/Users/olufnielsen/code/rails/youngdeveloper/app/views/devise", "/Users/olufnielsen/code/rails/youngdeveloper/app/views", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.3/app/views""

Comment: Did you generate the devise views? You should now have app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb (and others) in your app.

Comment: Yes.. they are in app/views/devise/* and my controller is in app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: Hmmm... Is there any reason registrations_controller isn't at a higher level, e.g. app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb, rather than under the users directory? You are close to getting this working... you are now back to regular Rails template loading issues.

Comment: class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  
  def new
    render 'devise/registrations/new'
    super
  end
  
  def create
    super
    @profile = Profile.new
  end
end kinda works but gives me this fail http://pastebin.com/bM4J8SGm

Comment: The nil object error may be due to your namespaced 'resource' (resource is your user model in your example). The form_for call doesn't know how to create the correct user Model object. Again, I think this may be due to your nesting of the controller inside the users directory. This is because Devise infers the type of resource for you.

Comment: Hi, Scott. Thanks for your big help! I now got it working, what did the trick was before_create, then it created the profil eautomaticly for the user ;)! - THank

Comment: Sweet! Using that before_create filter was a great idea :-)

Answer (score 6):

There's not really any need to involve the controller in this; models can (and should) do all of the heavy lifting here.

I'm assuming that you have a relationship between `User` and `Profile` models, in which case, you should just be able to do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile # could be a belongs_to, but has_one makes more sense

  after_create :create_user_profile

  def create_user_profile
    create_profile(:column => 'value', ...)
  end
end
```