# Keeping a query-string in devise sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, query-string

I am using rails with devise for signing up. Also I added an invite code, so not everybody can sign up.

The invite code gets transmitted via query-string like "/users/sign_up?invite_code=wajdpapojapsd" and gets added to a hidden field of the sign-up form with "f.hidden_field :invite_code, :value => params[:invite_code]".

This works pretty well. The only problem is that if the sign up doesn't get validated and rejected, devise redirects to "/users" and loses the query string with the invite_code in it.

As the email stays in the sign up form after the failed attempt, I believe that this should also work for the invite code. As a worst case solution redirecting :back after a failed sign up and losing the email, but keeping the invite code, would be better than the way it works now.

EDIT: By now I ve set up a registration controller for devise, but don't have any idea how to get the desired behavior.

Any help on how to keep the query string or just the invite code would be awesome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a working solution by now.

I used jstr's answer to set up the controller for devise and added the "session" line.

```
class MyRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  prepend_view_path "app/views/devise"

  def create
    super
    session[:invite_code] = resource.invite_code
  end

  def update
    super
  end
end
```

Afterwards I added following to the devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<% if params[:invite_code]
  @invite_code = params[:invite_code]
else
  @invite_code = session[:invite_code]
end %>
```

And changed the hidden_field to

```
<%= f.hidden_field :invite_code, :value => @invite_code %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to make your own subclassed Devise controllers to get this to work.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546122/387310) has a good description of how to to this.

The basics:

1. Install the Devise views if you haven't already with `rails generate devise:views`
2. Create a subclassed `Devise::RegistrationsController`
3. Update your Devise routes declaration to get Devise to use your subclassed controller

Comment: This seems helpful. Unfortunately I have no idea what to do afterwards. Is this helpful to both possible solutions or only the worst case one?

Comment: Start by checking out the Devise::RegistrationsController source code (it's on GitHub, Google it). Base your implementation on that. I'd say you're going to have to know a bit of Ruby and have a good understanding of Rails to get this to work. Providing an actual implementation is outside the scope of your question ;)

Comment: I had a look at it, but unfortunately it doesn't help me much. Well to stay in the scope of the question, I am interested in why the email stays in the form, while the invite_code doesn't.
According to https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb
if a sign up fails it does following two lines:
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
I seem to understand the lines, but not why they cause this behavior (Email stays the same, while invitecode doesn't)

Comment: Especially as deleting "clean_up_passwords resource" doesn't have any impact on my problem :/

Comment: Just re-read your question. You could try adding `attr_accessor :invite_code` and updating `attr_accessible` to include invite_code in your User model. That should allow you to persist the invite code value when the sign up view is re-rendered on failure.

Comment: I did it with session[:invite_code] now. Unfortunately SO was down yesterday, so I couldn't write back.

Comment: Anyways, your Tut and links were very helpful to the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@James Lever 's solution has one disadvantage. *invite_code* remains in session. In some solutions it can cause problems. The alternative soultion would be:

```
def create
  # set invite code to session:
  session[:invite_code] = resource.invite_code
  # here the form is rendered and invite code from session would be used:
  super

  # delete invite code from session: 
  session.delete('invite_code')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't use instance variable such

```
@invite_code = params[:invite_code]
```

Then when a sign up didn't pass validation, you can use that variable in the view which will be displayed for failed sign up.

I mean before, it's redirected, you should keep the invite code parameters with instance variable. sorry if i'm mistaken.

Comment: I just added following to the view and it unfortunately didn't help:
<% unless @ invite_code
@ invite_code = params[:invite_code]
end %>
Did I understand it wrong? Does this usually do the trick?

Comment: The whitespace between @ invite_code is just so stackoverflow doesn't get confused with their notifications

Comment: There actually should be no output to this. What is the = for?